# How to add a JavaScript item to a Visual Studio Solution

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

In VS 2012 in Solution Explorer I right click on the Solution -> Add -> New item. In the list I see different items such as a text file, web page, style sheet, but there is no .js item. So far the only way for me is to create it in notepad++, save it and then add it as an existing item. Is there a faster way?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click the "Web" heading on the left bar of the window under "Visual C# Items". You will see "JavaScript File" appear. You could just as easily however add a file of any type and simply change the extension to .js.

Comment: I don't have this. I posted a screenshot.

Comment: Right click on your *project* and add the item. That window comes up when you click on the *solution*.